# Django Rest Framework object level permission on POST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to make sure the request.user can only issue a POST request to create a forum topic in which they are the auther. With PUT and DELETE I'm able to achieve that by using the `has_object_permission` but with POST I'm not able to do that, I'm guessing because the object hasn't been created yet.

```
class TopicPermission(IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly):
    """
    Any user should be able to read topics but only authenticated 
    users should be able to create new topics. An owner or moderator 
    should be able to update a discussion or delete.
    """
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Instance must have an attribute named `author` or moderator
        return obj.author == request.user or request.user.forum_moderator
```

How would I go about verifying `request.user == obj.author` in POST requests?

Comment: Do you have an `author` field on your serializer that you are trying to ensure is set to the current user when cresting the object? There are better ways to do that than by doing a permission check.

Comment: yes, it's not about that. It works fine for PUT and DELETE, but with POST has_object_permission does not work.

Comment: By "does not work" do you mean "is not called", "triggers an error", or "never passes"? It's not clear what you are trying to do in your question, and it [smells like an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/159034).

Comment: FWIW: I bet @KevinBrown meant that `has_object_permission` gets called after the new object is saved.

Comment: I have this problem also for `PUT`/`PATCH` methods. It return false but doesn't work. In other way it let all users to update a post of specific user. Can you help me please?

Comment: For those facing this issue, POST request will be accessible in "has_object_permission", you need to handle it in "has_permission"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up doing the validation in the viewset instead of the serializer:

```
class TopicViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (TopicPermission, )
    queryset = Topic.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TopicSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        verify that the POST has the request user as the obj.author
        """
        if request.data["author"] == str(request.user.id):
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            self.perform_create(serializer)
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=201, headers=headers)
        else:
            return Response(status=403)
```